# Unhide an android application through dialing a number

Tags: android, android-launcher

I have a spy application i can hide its icon from menu by clicking on button ,but i am unable to unhide through phone dialer, 
i have use the following **JAVA code**:

```
 public class launchReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
@Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    String number=intent.getStringExtra(Intent.EXTRA_PHONE_NUMBER);
    String compare_num="#5555";
    if(number.equals(compare_num))
    {Intent myintent=new Intent(context,com.example.hide.MainActivity.class);
        myintent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        context.startActivity(myintent);
        abortBroadcast();} }}
```

**MANIFEST Code**

```
<receiver android:name=".launchReceiver"
android:enabled="true" >

<intent-filter android:priority="0">

 <action android:name="android.intent.action.NEW_OUTGOING_CALL"/>

</intent-filter>

</receiver>
```

Answer (score 1):

use this code :

```
 public class launchReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    String phoneNumber = getResultData();
    if (phoneNumber == null) {
      phoneNumber = intent.getStringExtra(Intent.EXTRA_PHONE_NUMBER);
    }

         if(phoneNumber.equals("#5555")){ // DialedNumber checking.
        setResultData(null);

        // Start Application
        Intent i=new Intent(context,MainActivity.class);
        i.putExtra("extra_phone", phoneNumber);
        i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        context.startActivity(i);
         }    
}

}
```

and remove android:priority from manifest.

add permission

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.PROCESS_OUTGOING_CALLS"/>
```

in manifest.

Comment: In manifest i declared the the Reciever as is it right??
   <receiver android:name=".launchReceiver"
               android:enabled="true" >
    <intent-filter android:priority="0">
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.NEW_OUTGOING_CALL"/>
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>

Comment: just remove :  android:priority="0"

Comment: Thankx for help but when i dial the number #5555 then apps unfortunatly closed.it is giving exception.

Comment: Caused by: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.example.hide/com.example.hide.MainActivity}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?

Comment: try adding package name before MainActivity.class.

Comment: Got same exception :(

Comment: Caused by: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.example.hide/com.example.hide.MainActivity}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?

Answer (score 1):

**IMPORTANT**:It is a tricky way to solve this issue.And see these points and try

1) Unhide your application in Broadcast class after matching the number.
2) Then open your activity using Intent
3) When open your activity then in your activity in onDestroy() method again hide the application with some Boolean value.